# Проверка на антиплагиат

Tags: android, юридические-аспекты

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть. Во время написания дипломной работы(мобильной программы на андроиде) я задавал вопросы на стековерфлоу, тостере и в других различных форумах по программированию. Сейчас сделал проверку на уникальность, программа определяет мой текст программы как плагиат и показывает те форумы, где я задавал вопрос. Что делать? Как это сказать завтра во время проверки на антиплагиат и как доказать, что это информация моя?

Comment: Переименовать переменные?..

Comment: зачем? это же мой код программы.

Comment: Всё зависит от вашей цели. Если цель - сдать, пройдя проверку - можно попробовать переименовать. Если цель - сдать, объяснив, что код ваш, хоть вы и спрашивали как его написать на форумах, то вам остаётся лишь надеяться что тот, кому вы объяснять будете посчитает ваши слова убедительными.

Comment: а с каких пор текст программы проходит на антиплагиат?) я сам сдавал android приложение и проверяли только воду, но не код программы

Comment: код в приложении. несколько классов добавил

Comment: Какова процентная доля кода, который распознаётся, как написанный не вами?

Comment: "Тот неловкий момент, когда антиплагиат говорит, что автор твоей программы -- не ты, а stackoverflow" (C) A K

Comment: При необходимости, просто объясните что и как работает.

Comment: Облом) 89 % оригинальность показал антиплагиат проверка универа)